# String Operations (substring) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

If I have a string like follows:

"abc; expire=Thu, 16-Oct-2014 16:46:53 GMT; path=/;", and I am trying to extract everything between `expire=` and the next `;` so I can get the timestamp, how would I do this in Swift? I am totally confused by the ideas of characters and StringIndex. I feel like the following code will give me the locations in the string of `" expire="`:

`var range = cookie!.rangeOfString(" expires=");`

I don't however understand where I should go from there.

In Java-like languages the algorithm would be something like:

1) Locate index of "expires=";

2) Take substring of everything after "expires=" to end of full string;

3) Look in substring for first occurrence of ";"

4) Everything from index 0 to index found in 3 is the expire timestamp.

How do you go about working with Swift strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd go with @dasblinkenlight's solution of using a regular expression, but if you want to do something more like the algorithm in your question, you can:

```
let cookie: String = "abc; expires=Thu, 16-Oct-2014 16:46:53 GMT; path=/;"
if let range = cookie.rangeOfString(" expires=") {
    let expiresAndPath = cookie[range.endIndex..<cookie.endIndex]
    if let semicolonRange = expiresAndPath.rangeOfString(";") {
        let expires = expiresAndPath[expiresAndPath.startIndex..<semicolonRange.startIndex]
        /* do something with expires */
    }
}
```

Step-by-step:

1. Locate index of "expires="

`let range = cookie.rangeOfString(" expires=")`

2. Take substring of everything after "expires=" to end of full string

`let expiresAndPath = cookie[range.endIndex..<cookie.endIndex]`

3. Look in substring for first occurrence of ";"

`let semicolonRange = expiresAndPath.rangeOfString(";")`

4. Everything from index 0 to index found in 3 is the expire timestamp.

`let expires = expiresAndPath[expiresAndPath.startIndex..<semicolonRange.startIndex]`

Comment: I am accepting your answer as this follows the algorithm I spelled out in OP. Although I am finding this range stuff to be a little wild coming from a Java background, this definitely helped me understand this a lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift you can use regex to search strings, without having to deal with `NSRegularExpression` explicitly:

```
let str = "abc; expire=Thu, 16-Oct-2014 16:46:53 GMT; path=/;"
let range = str.rangeOfString("(?<=expire=)[^;]*", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
if let range = optRange? {
    print(str.substringWithRange(range))
} else {
    print("Not found")
}
```

The regular expression is straightforward: `[^;]*` means "a sequence of characters up to the first semicolon"; `(?<=expire=)` means "match only when preceded by `expire=` string".

[Demo.](http://www.runswiftlang.com/s/hl_4Zfow)

Comment: I am not against using regular expressions if necessary, but shouldn't there be a couple basic string operations that would enable me to do this without them?

Comment: @thatidiotguy Absolutely, it is possible to rewrite this as a sequence of finding substrings, arriving at the same result after a sequence of simple subtractions. This would make a four-line solution out of a one-line solution, which is suboptimal from the point of view of the reader of the code.